# How do you see all the tweets made by a person?

Tags: twitter

I am using a browser and going to twitter.com.

I am at a person or organization's page, for example [twitter.com/realDonaldTrump](https://twitter.com/realDonaldTrump). I see only three or four latest tweets from that person under the Tweets tab. It is also the same under the Tweets & Replies tab.

How do I get a list of all tweets ever made by a Twitter user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to see all the tweets from a specific user is to use the `from:` operator in Twitter's search box, coupled with the username of the desired account. For example:

```
from:Twitter
```

Will give you [all the tweets authored by @Twitter](https://twitter.com/search?q=from%3ATwitter&src=typed_query&f=live).

You can narrow this to include or exclude reply tweets made by the user to other tweets. For example:

```
from:Twitter filter:replies
```

will give you only the [replies @Twitter made to other users](https://twitter.com/search?q=from%3ATwitter%20filter%3Areplies&src=typed_query&f=live).

There are many more operators you can add in combination with the `from:` operator to get really intereting results like only tweets with links or only tweets  that have been shared or liked X number of times.